# How recover the click of user in dropdown list

Tags: php, forms, isset

I have a dropdown list in html,  and I would like recover the click of the user.
For example, if in my dropdown list,  I have 50 possibility,  like ( foot,basket,tennis.....),

I would like recover the click of the person (where he clicks).  I try do it in php,

I wanted use if(isset....)  for every click  but it would be so long, so I have to find a method to recover the click of the user without use 50 if (isset)

Here my forms ( what I tried to optimise):

```
<form id="form-recipe" action="essaie4.php?IDR=<?php echo($ET2['IDR'])?>" method="POST">


      <label for="ing-select">Ingrédient</label>
      <select id="ing-select" class="ingredients" name="ingId" onChange="header("Location: essaie4.php?$IDR=<?php echo $_GET['$IDR'];?>">
                    <option value="1"<?php if ($_GET['ingId'] == 1){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>salade</option>
                    <option value="2">steak</option>
                    <option value="3">pain</option>
                    <option value="4">oignons</option>
                    <option value="5">ketchup </option>
                    <option value="6">totame</option>
                    <option value="7">sauceuranium</option>
                    <option value="8">cornichon</option>

              </select>
      <label for="quantity">Quantité</label>
      <select class="quantity" name="quantity">
        <option value=0> 0 (Supprimer l'ingrédient)</option><option value=1 selected >1</option><option value=2  >2</option><option value=3  >3</option><option value=4  >4</option><option value=5  >5</option>      </select>
        <input type="submit" class="input" value="VALIDER">
      <a class="button back" href="essaie3.php" title="">Retour à la page d'accueil</a>
            </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to read me !!!

Answer (score -1):

In PHP run

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

You should see what's in there and "quantity" should be one of those properties. You can access the value with:

```
$value = $_POST['quantity'];
```